# Draw GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE vs. GL_TEXTURE_2D

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-3

I'm trying to make a function to draw both 2D textures and Rectangle Textures.

It draws the 2D ones perfectly fine. However, when drawing any Rectangle textures, it draws them completely white..

```
GLuint LoadImage(std::string ImageTitle, GLenum Target)
{
    Image Img(("Images/" + ImageTitle).c_str());
    std::vector<std::uint8_t> Buffer;
    ImageToBuffer(Buffer, Img);

    GLuint ID;
    glGenTextures(1, &ID);
    glBindTexture(Target, ID);
    glTexParameteri(Target, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, Target == GL_TEXTURE_2D ? GL_REPEAT : GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(Target, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, Target == GL_TEXTURE_2D ? GL_REPEAT : GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(Target, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(Target, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(Target, 0, GL_RGB, Img.Width(), Img.Height(), 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, Buffer.data());
    return ID;
}

void DrawTexture(GLenum Target, GLuint ID, float X1, float Y1, float X2, float Y2)
{
    GLfloat ViewPort[4];
    glGetFloatv(GL_VIEWPORT, ViewPort);

    glEnable(Target);
    glBindTexture(Target, ID);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        glVertex2f(X1, Y1);

        glTexCoord2f(0, Target == GL_TEXTURE_2D ? 1 : ViewPort[3]);
        glVertex2f(X1, Y2);

        glTexCoord2f(Target == GL_TEXTURE_2D ? 1 : ViewPort[2], Target == GL_TEXTURE_2D ? 1 : ViewPort[3]);
        glVertex2f(X2, Y2);

        glTexCoord2f(Target == GL_TEXTURE_2D ? 1 : ViewPort[2], 0);
        glVertex2f(X2, Y1);
    glEnd();
    glDisable(Target);
}
```

I also tried using `glTextCoordf(X, Y)` where X and Y are 1 instead of ViewPort Width/Height. Tried using the Width/Height, still nothing. Tried Texture Width and Height. I tried loading the Rect as a 2D as well. No luck.

Nothing works :S Yet it somehow works for Texture2D.

I use it like:

```
GLuint ID = LoadImage("RECT_116.png", GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE);

//Do other stuff here..

DrawTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, ID, X1, Y1, X2, Y2);
```

and it fails but when I do it on a 2D Texture:

```
GLuint ID = LoadImage("2D_116.png", GL_TEXTURE_2D);

//Do other stuff here..

DrawTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ID, X1, Y1, X2, Y2);
```

it works..  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: And you're sure your hardware **and** driver support rectangle textures? What does `glGetError` say?

Comment: "*I'm trying to make a function to draw both 2D textures and Rectangle Textures.*" Why? You tagged this with OpenGL 3, so clearly you're using a version of OpenGL that allows for NPOT regular textures. So what are you using rectangles for that you need to draw them with the same function?

Answer (score 2):

From http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml

> If target is GL_PROXY_TEXTURE_2D, GL_PROXY_TEXTURE_1D_ARRAY,
>   GL_PROXY_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, or GL_PROXY_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, no data is
>   read from data, but all of the texture image state is recalculated,
>   checked for consistency, and checked against the implementation's
>   capabilities. If the implementation cannot handle a texture of the
>   requested texture size, it sets all of the image state to 0, but does
>   not generate an error (see glGetError). To query for an entire mipmap
>   array, use an image array level greater than or equal to 1.
>
> If target is GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE or one of the
>   GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP targets, data is read from data as a sequence of
>   signed or unsigned bytes, shorts, or longs, or single-precision
>   floating-point values, depending on type. These values are grouped
>   into sets of one, two, three, or four values, depending on format, to
>   form elements. Each data byte is treated as eight 1-bit elements, with
>   bit ordering determined by GL_UNPACK_LSB_FIRST (see glPixelStore).

Thus it seems like the check for consistency may fail for some reason.

You seem to be doing different boundary conditions depending on GL_TEXTURE_2D or GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE at

```
glTexParameteri(Target, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, 
    Target == GL_TEXTURE_2D ? GL_REPEAT : GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

Have you tried removing that conditional to see if that changes the situation?

Comment: I cannot see though how that spec quote gives any insight what might be wrong, neither how the wrapping behaviour should change the situation (but Ok, that is at least worth a try).